# API filtering with pivot table

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel 7 and i've made an API to fetch data with a VUE component.

I want to filter restaurants based on their type of food. So if i query "pizza" i want to show only restaurants that make pizza.
getTypes is a many to many relation.

```
 public function restaurants(Request $request)
{
    $ricerca = $request->input('query');

    $users = Restaurant::with(array('getTypes' => function ($query) use ($ricerca) {

        $query->where('name', "LIKE", "%" . $ricerca . "%");
    }))->get();

   
   

    return response()->json($users);
}
```

I tried this, but this way i don't have access to other genres, if a restaurant make pizza and meat, i don't see meat anymore.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a many to many relation with restaurant and pizza.

get an array which restaurant  make pize,

```
$array = [];
```

or simple var

```
$array = $request('query');
```

and put this array in query.

```
$data = Project::whereHas('restorant_pizza', function ($q) use ($array) {

         $q->whereIn('restorant_pizza.pizza_id', $array);

    })->get();
```

I think this idea will help you